# How to check if a TR contains a TD with a specific CSS class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I know you can use `.find` to find `td:contains('text')`, but if I have a tr with say, 3 td's, and one of the td's *might* have `class="specialclass someotherclass"` (may potentially have other classes in addition to special class), how do I use jquery to check if a TR contains a TD of `specialclass`?

Comment: `if($('tr').find('td.specialclass').length>0 || $('tr').find('td[class*="specialclass"]').length>0) ...` that's your check and direct query selection goes the same way. What you're looking for?

Comment: I know we get embarrassed sometimes about answering questions that SEEM easy to *us*, but let's keep the comment area for comments and post answers as answers!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To select any `tr` that has a `td.specialclass`:

```
$('tr:has(td.specialclass)')
```

Or if you have a `tr` (represented by `this`) and you simply want to check if it has such a `td`:

```
if ($(this).find('td.specialclass').length)
```

Comment: I guess you beat me by like 30 seconds. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
if ($("tr").has("td.specialclass").length > 0) {
    // has specialclass
}
```

or

```
if ($("tr:has(td.specialclass)").length > 0) {
    // has specialclass
}
```