# find whether the datatable has any row or is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript

i write code that check weather any row exist in datatable or not i write some code please check and give me suggestion what I do for it.

```js
$('#del').click( function () {

              
              tab.row('.selected').remove().draw();
              
             if(window.clck===true){

              if($("#table").length > -1){

         // toastr.options.timeOut = 1500;
         // toastr.success("empity");

         toastr.options.timeOut = 1500;
         toastr.success('deleted');

           }

     else if($("#table").length <= 0){

       toastr.options.timeOut = 1500;
         toastr.success('empity');

          }

   }

   else
   {
      toastr.options.timeOut = 1500;
      toastr.success('please select a row');
   }
                                                           
     } );
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360450/how-to-check-if-a-tr-contains-a-td-with-a-specific-css-class-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

if ( ! tab.data().any() ) {

```
            toastr.options.timeOut = 1500;
            toastr.success('table is empty');

        }


           else{
                    tab.row('.selected').remove().draw();
                    toastr.options.timeOut = 1500;
                    toastr.success('deleted');

           }
```